# Entity framework not working after adding a column in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4.0 and EF application I have added a new column in the database - updated Model from database in the edxm file. Made some changes in the controllers, build and published the site again. Also added the same column in the database on web server. After deploying the changes the insert code is not working. Its all working fine locally and I m not getting any error on the server and don't know how to go about troubleshooting this. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: can you post the error your getting here?

Comment: that's the problem. I don't see an error on the server but the insert is not happening in the table

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will get it working after double checking everything but just in case, you can override `SaveChanges()` method of `DbContext` class (assuming Ef 4.1+) there you can see all changes and what happens to them by loggin, debugging etc.

Comment: Check for datatype, length, nullable and other indexes and constraints. Try generating edmx file with hosted database and find if any changes oocuur.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is silly but did you remember to change connectionstring ?

Comment: I did not touch the web.config on the webserver and all other database operations seem to be working as normal except this table

Comment: If i understand you you have 2 database. One is develpoment db ans second is product. Try use for moment product db like development. (reconfigure this in web.config connection string)